# Concerning the closure of a set in this topology

Tags: general-topology

It is not hard to see that the set $\mathcal{I} = \{ (a, \infty) \vert a \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{\mathbb{R}\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ is a basis for a topology of semi-infinite intervals.

Given some arbitrary element of this basis (that is neither the empty set nor the whole space), I would like to find its closure. Our set is trivially open, so it is equal to its interior, and thus we simply need the boundary points to see its closure.

The nature of our basis elements makes it clear that the point $a$ would be the one point on the boundary of said element (since all open sets that contain it have nontrivial intersection with both the interior of our element and $ \mathbb{R}$ sans this element). Naturally, I would believe that the closure of my basis element is $ [a, \infty)$. However, on complementation we obtain the set $ (- \infty, a)$, which is not open in our topology since, I claim, it cannot be obtained through an arbitrary union of basis elements.

This would lead me to believe that the *true* closure of any given basis element is simply the whole space since its complement is trivially open and also contains the boundary point in question. Is this the case? How could I have seen this sooner, if so? Also if so, why does it *seem* to be the case here that the closure is not the interior with the boundary? Furthermore, would the closure of *any* open set in this topology also be the whole space, assuming it is the case for our basis elements as I have explained?

These questions are quite basic, but I have no mathematicians nearby to dispel my confusion. Any and all help appreciated.

Edit: Thank you for your help. I understand the problem and concept much better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the family you've written is not just a basis for a topology, but *the topology itself*.
With this in mind, one should start by looking at the class of closed subsets, which is $$\{(-\infty,a]\,:\,a\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{\Bbb R,\emptyset\}$$

and then notice that the only one containing a non-empty open set is $\Bbb R$. So, every non-empty open set is dense. Finally, the boundary of $(x,\infty)$ is in fact $(-\infty,x]$.

Comment: I see, well said. Still I am confused as to why this interval is the boundary. For example $(a-1, \infty)$ intersects nontrivially with $(a, \infty)$ and the interval $(a-1, a]$, but not with the rest of this semi-infinite (to the left) claimed boundary, $(- \infty, a-1]$.

Comment: Perhaps I should say "the open sets that contain our chosen one need not contain what you claim is the boundary, but they do need to contain just the one point."

Comment: @Casquibaldo You should rather observe that the closure of a set is the intersection of all the closed subsets that contain it. If there is only one, the intersection is quite trivial.

Comment: Nevermind, I understood. Also this is good advice.

Answer (score 1):

If $B=(a,\infty)$ is a basic open set, then for all $x > a$, $x \in B \subseteq \overline{B}$ and if $x \le a$, any basic open subset containing $x$ is of the form $B' = (b,\infty)$ with $b <x$. Such a $B'$ clearly intersects $B$. So $x \in \overline{B}$ as well.

Alternatively note that for any two non-empty open sets $O_1, O_2$ we have $O_1 \cap O_2 \neq \emptyset$. This immediately implies that $\overline{O}= \mathbb{R}$ for all $O = (a, \infty)$.

The boundary of $O = (a,\infty)$ is then $\overline{O}\setminus \operatorname{int}(O) = \mathbb{R}\setminus (a, \infty) = (-\infty, a]$

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that if all nonempty open sets have pairwise nonempty intersection then the closure of any one of them is the whole space?

Comment: @Casquibaldo $(a,\infty) \cap (b, \infty) = (\max(a,b), \infty) \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Casquibaldo $x$ is the closure of $O$ iff any open set $O'$ containing $x$ has $O' \cap O$ non-empty.

Comment: Nevermind, I just understood

Comment: @Casquibaldo it’s immediate: fix one non-empty $O$. Then any $x\in X$ lies in the closure of $O$ because any open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $O$ because all pairs of non-empty open sets intersect. Done.

Comment: yes, it is quite clear. My mind was in a fog, thank you.